# Local storage is set to wrong domain in Cypress

Tags: cypress, e2e-testing

Trying to test two subdomains in integration.

However, `localStorage` is always set to first visited subdomain.

Is it possible to set `localStorage` value to the later visited subdomain (bar.company.com) in the example below?

```
describe('Login', () => {
  it('Logins foo', () => {
    cy.visit('https://foo.company.com');
    
    localStorage.setItem('foo', 'foo');  
  });

  it('Logins bar', () => {
    cy.visit('https://bar.company.com');

    // this will set the entry to foo.company.com
    localStorage.setItem('bar', 'bar');   
  });
});
```

Now if we check `localStorage` at `bar.company.com` it is empty.
And `foo.company.com` has the both `foo` and `bar` entries.

Comment: cy.visit yields window, maybe you can set localStorage via that window object?

Comment: Apparently, yielded window object has no `localStorage`. 
Having the following error
`"Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'setItem')"`

Comment: Which value does cy.getAllLocalStorage() yield if you run it at the end of your tests?

Comment: `{ "foo.company.com": { "foo": "foo", "bar": "bar" }, "bar.company.com": { } }`

Answer (score 1):

You should either set `testIsolation: true` or call `cy.clearAllLocalStorage()` before all tests.

TestIsolation is designed to overcome this sort of issue, but you may not want it if there is some sort of continuity between tests (i.e data carries over).

Here is a reproducible example. There are two contexts, one with testIsolation on and one with it off.

Comment out the `cy.clearAllLocalStorage()` and you will see the tests start to fail.

Note that localstorage entries persist across runs in the Cypress UI.

```js
context("localstorage - isolated", { testIsolation: true }, () => {

  it("one", () => {
    cy.visit("https://docs.cypress.io");
    localStorage.setItem("one", "1");
    cy.getAllLocalStorage().should("deep.eq", {
      "https://docs.cypress.io": { one: "1" }
    });
  })

  it("two", () => {
    cy.visit('https://example.com/')
    localStorage.setItem("two", "2");
    cy.getAllLocalStorage().should("deep.eq", {
      "https://example.com": { two: "2" }
    });
  })
})

context("localstorage - not isolated", { testIsolation: false }, () => {
  
  before(() => {
    cy.clearAllLocalStorage()
  })

  it("one", () => {
    cy.visit('https://docs.cypress.io');
    localStorage.setItem("one", "1");
    cy.getAllLocalStorage().should("deep.eq", {
      "https://docs.cypress.io": { one: "1" }
    });
  })

  it("two", () => {
    cy.visit('https://example.com')
    localStorage.setItem("two", "2");
    cy.getAllLocalStorage().should("deep.eq", {
      "https://example.com": { two: "2" }
    });
  })
})
```